# how can i remove ' from my output in python

Tags: python, split

```
msg1 = "   Facebook already uses AI to Filter Fake stories from the feeds of users "  
Desired output = [Facebook , already, uses, AI, to, Filter, Fake, stories, from, the, feeds, of, users ]​
```

My code:

```
msg1 = "  Facebook already uses AI to Filter Fake stories from the feeds of users"
print(msg1.split())

Actual output = ['Facebook', 'already', 'uses', 'AI', 'to', 'Filter', 'Fake', 'stories', 'from', 'the', 'feeds', 'of', 'users']
```

I'm just getting started into python. i may be using the wrong function or missing anything to remove ' from the output.
How can i achieve this simple goal.

Comment: Since you're new to Python, _why_ do you (think) you need `[Facebook , already, uses,...` as your desired output, instead of `['Facebook', 'already', 'uses'...`? See the first answer of the linked duplicate for an explanation. You realize that the "desired output" version is _not_ a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msg1 = "  Facebook already uses AI to Filter Fake stories from the feeds of users"
output = str(msg1.split()).replace("'", "")
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

**This should work**

```
msg1 = "   Facebook already uses AI to Filter Fake stories from the feeds of users ".split()
print(*msg1, sep=" ")
```

You can modify the sep so so that you can have the desired character to be in the spaces between each elements. And the default value for sep would be " ".